# Does there exist a non-isotrivial fibration of genus two over P^1  with only 3 singular fibres of general type surfaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fibration, higher-genus-curves, algebraic-surfaces

We will work over the complex numbers C.

This question is based on Beauville's article :
 there exist a non-isotrivial fibration of genus 2 over P^1  with only 3 singular fibres.
but not know for general type surfaces

Comment: Voting to close. It's not clear to me exactly what question you are trying to ask. (Providing a clearer reference to this article of Beauville would be helpful, for a start.)

Comment: I don't see why this question should be closed. It is only poorly presented. It would make more sense to encourage and help the person asking to improve it. I vote to keep it open. I also vote to encourage MO users to be a little more patient and compassionate towards others. 

Comment: I agree with Sandor's comment. Related question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64112/does-there-exist-a-non-trivial-semi-stable-curve-of-genus-1-with-only-4-singular/64123#64123

Comment: I also agree with Sandor's comment!

Comment: Agree with Sandor's comment!